# How do I get rid of these small black areas in my PCB routing

Tags: mesh

I make my PCB using a 3D printer. When I expose my PCB and finally develop it, I notice certain areas in my routing that disappear.

I then looked at my routing in Blender, and there are certain areas in the routing where there are small black areas (these are the areas where when my PCB is developed the routing is part gone.

I tried all the things that I know (not much) and the black areas are still there in Blender. Take a look at the picture and maybe you could steer me in the right direction to get rid of these black areas

[image].

Steps are as follows:

1. I use Inkscape or FlatCam to make a .svg of my black and white picture (jpg...in the Paint program in Windows 10.
2. In blender ... Delete the box, light and camera
3. Import the .svg file.
4. highlight all the parts 1 thru 28
5. Then I go to objects and scroll down till I get to the middle mesh. Then I join them all
6. Add a Solidfy modifier
7. Use tool "3dprint"; choose my folder and click on STL

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141986/discussion-on-question-by-patrick-cambre-how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-small-black-a).

Comment: @Patrick OK, Posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean-up in 2 moves, making your mesh fit for extrusion / *Solidify*

First, get rid of excessive triangulation by using <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve, restricting to a low angle to preserve the sampled curvatures:

[image]

But that still leaves co-linear edges without coincident vertices, so merging or welding won't join them:

[image]

There are 2 ways I've found of merging those.

Either create a fresh plane encompassing the mesh, below it, and from an orthographic view down Z, [Knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) the mesh down on to the plane. The Mesh-faces should remain selected, you can  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> select inverse, and delete unwanted faces.

But it's easier, in the header, to switch on Auto-merge, with 'Split Edges and Faces' checked. Just hit <kbd>G</kbd> with all selected, and that seems to do the trick:

[image]

Here are the interfaces to the tools:

[image]

and the result, after extrusion.

[image]

The export and re-import to .stl seems OK, but I am disappointed not to have found a more automated route, exclusively via modifiers or the like, to save work, if this needs repeating often.

[image]